# Issues with Docker Swarm running TeamCity using rexray/ebs for drive persistence in AWS EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, data-persistence, aws-ebs

I'm quite new to Docker but have started thinking about production set-ups, hence needing to crack the challenge of data persistence when using Docker Swarm. I decided to start by creating my deployment infrastructure (TeamCity for builds and NuGet plus the "registry" [https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/] for storing images).

I've started with TeamCity. Obvious this needs data persistence in order to work. I am able to run TeamCity in a container with an EBS drive and everything looks like it is working just fine - TeamCity is working through the set-up steps and my TeamCity drives appear in AWS EBS, but then the worker node TeamCity gets allocated to shuts down and the install process stops.

Here are all the steps I'm following:

**Phase 1 - Machine Setup:**

- Create one AWS instance for master
- Create two AWS instances for workers
- All are 64-bit Ubuntu t2.mircro instances
- Create three elastic IPs for convenience and assign them to the above machines.
- Install Docker on all nodes using this: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
- Install Docker Machine on all nodes using this: https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/
- Install Docker Compose on all nodes using this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

**Phase 2 - Configure Docker Remote on the Master:**

```
$ sudo docker run -p 2375:2375 --rm -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jarkt/docker-remote-api
```

**Phase 3 - install the rexray/ebs plugin on all machines:**

```
$ sudo docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions rexray/ebs REXRAY_PREEMPT=true EBS_ACCESSKEY=XXX EBS_SECRETKEY=YYY
```

[I lifted the correct values from AWS for XXX and YYY]

- I test this using:

  $ sudo docker volume create --driver=rexray/ebs --name=delete --opt=size=2

  $ sudo docker volume rm delete
- All three nodes are able to create and delete drives in AWS EBS with no issue.

**Phase 4 - Setup the swarm:**

- Run this on the master:

  $ sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr eth0:2377
- This gives the command to run on each of the workers, which looks like this:

  $ sudo docker swarm join --token XXX 1.2.3.4:2377
- These execute fine on the worker machines.

**Phase 5 - Set up visualisation using Remote Powershell on my local machine:**

```
$ $env:DOCKER_HOST="{master IP address}:2375"

$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c viz.yml viz
```

viz.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    viz:
        image: dockersamples/visualizer
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role==manager
```

- This works fine and allows me to visualise my swarm.

**Phase 6 - Install TeamCity using Remote Powershell on my local machine:**

```
$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml infra
```

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  teamcity:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:2017.1.2
    volumes:
        - teamcity-server-datadir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
        - teamcity-server-logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
    ports:
        - "80:8111"

volumes:
  teamcity-server-datadir:
   driver: rexray/ebs
  teamcity-server-logs:
   driver: rexray/ebs
```

- [Incorporating NGINX as a proxy is a later step on my to do list.]
- I can see both the required drives appear in AWS EBS and the container appear in my swarm visualisation.
- However, after a while of seeing the progress screen in TeamCity the worker machine containing the TeamCity instance shuts down and the process abruptly ends.
- I'm at a loss as to what to do next. I'm not even sure where to look for logs.

Any help gratefully received!

Cheers,

Steve.

Comment: P.S. I'm not wedded to the idea of using rexray/ebs but it did look like the most popular and simple way to achieve data persistence after some extension Googling. I really like the idea of keeping the data in a separate EBS volume.

Comment: OK, I did some research into using EFS for shared drives in AWS and set that up between my three servers. This ended up having the same error, so I don't think the issue is with the rexray/ebs plugin. I wondering if it's a TeamCity issue. If you set up a TeamCity container using a local share under Docker Swarm it does work fine. Maybe TeamCity doesn't like using shared drives?

Comment: Update: Looks like I was wrong! It looks like it's Docker Swarm that's the problem. TeamCity doesn't even work using local storage (on the host) in Swarm mode. However, it does work well when using simple docker-compose. The rexray component works well using docker-compose too. So, what am I doing wrong with my Docker Swarm configuration that is causing TeamCity to stop after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's nice that you want to share your experiences with Docker Swarm, but Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to do so. Maybe you want to rather use a publishing platform like https://hackernoon.com or https://dev.to instead for this. Stack Overflow is a platform for finding the best answers for **specific** questions.

Comment: Apologies - I did actually start out by asking a question, but after a load more research I was able to answer my own questions so figured I should share what I'd learnt. It's actually quite hard to find good information out there about Docker Swarm. I'll think about adding a post to my own blog: http://code-smart.org.uk/

Comment: No need to apologize. I honestly think that it's great that you want to share your research! It's just that it's the wrong format for Stack Overflow. I'm sure you could turn this into a cool blog post and if you post it to https://dev.to (for example), you'll probably also get some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get logs for my service. First do this to list the services the stack creates:

```
$ sudo docker service ls
```

Then do this to see logs for the service:

```
$ sudo docker service logs --details {service name}
```

Now I just need to wade through the logs and see what went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I found the following error in the logs:

```
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  [2018-05-14 17:38:56,849]  ERROR - r.configs.dsl.DslPluginManager - DSL plugin compilation failed
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  exit code: 1
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  stdout: #
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 42012672 bytes for committing reserved memory.
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  # An error report file with more information is saved as:
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  # /opt/teamcity/bin/hs_err_pid125.log
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |
infra_teamcity.1.bhiwz74gnuio@ip-172-31-18-103    |  stderr: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e2dfe000, 42012672, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Which is making me think this is a memory problem. I'm going to try this again with a better AWS instance and see how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

Using a larger AWS instance solved the issue. :)

I then discovered that rexray/ebs doesn't like it when a container switches between hosts in my swarm - it duplicates the EBS volumes so that it keeps one per machine. My solution to this was to use an EFS drive in AWS and mount it to each possible host. I then updated the fstab file so that the drive is remounted on every reboot. Job done. Now to look into using a reverse proxy...